# Clear / x button in Wordpress input forms not showing

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to have the little "x" icon to the right in my input form but for some reasons it doesn't show. I guess there is something in my Wordpress theme that hides it.

My input field looks like this:

```
<input type="search">
```

How can I override the CSS (?) in order to show this?

EDIT:
Here is an example, as you can see the "x" icon is not shown when you start typing in the form: http://www.branschlosningar.se/inputfield.
Outside of Wordpress it works fine: http://branschlosningar.se/inputfield.html

Comment: You need more code for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Hi Andrew. The input field is a very siple input field that I use for filtering a list as I type (on the fly) so no <form> code present. I don't know where in the massive CSS code for the theme/Wordpress this is beeing blocked. Because of that I'm looking for a work around to override this.

Comment: @John can you then possibly link to an example? Or is this local development?

Comment: if you can show via snap it would help to suggest you solution.

Comment: Please share the CSS you wrote for your input. If you tried to add the "x" by a pseudo selector (like `:before` or `:after`), it doesn't show because input elements doesn't support pseudo selector for now. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4660434/3305116

Comment: Thank you all for your interest in helping me here! Very kind! Here is a simple example, as you see the inut field doesn't show the "x" icon when you start typing in it. http://www.branschlosningar.se/inputfield. Nothing custom here, just want a very simple input box to show the x.

Comment: I don't get it, how could you have an icon? There is no css attached on that input that could add any icon. Do you have the exemple of an other input that shows that icon you want?

Comment: Take a look here. No css, no script, no image icon. In (at least) chroe there is a "x" icon displayed: http://branschlosningar.se/inputfield.html